# Custom view within recyclerview not drawn after scroll

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-canvas

I have a custom view, which draws a concave shape (visualized with red rectangle on screenshot). This custom view is a part of my recycler view element layout, which also contains a plain view with background color (right part).

This is an extract of my custom view (without rotation, but same drawing methods):

```
    public class InvertedCircleView extends View {

    private Paint mPaint;
    private float mCanvasCenterX;

    private float mCenterCircleWidth, mCenterCircleHeight;


    public InvertedCircleView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        mPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

     [...]
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        canvas.drawPaint(mPaint);

        mPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));

        mCenterCircleWidth = canvas.getWidth();        
        mCenterCircleHeight = canvas.getHeight();        

        mCanvasCenterX = canvas.getWidth() / 2;

        canvas.drawOval(mCanvasCenterX - (mCenterCircleWidth / 2),
                -mCenterCircleHeight,
                mCanvasCenterX + (mCenterCircleWidth / 2),
                mCenterCircleHeight,
                mPaint);
    }
 }
```

When the recyclerview shows up the first time, everything looks fine. But when i scroll down (or up), the custom view part is not visible on all the new elements.

What i have tested so far:

- **setItemViewCacheSize** -> this helps, but when i scroll up again, it shows the same bad result
- **notifyDataSetChanged** -> this directly results in the "wrong" visualization for all elements

What may be the reason for this behaviour?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Found my mistake:
I used "mPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));" in the onDraw-function. But i forgot to reset Xfermode in the end.

I added the line " mPaint.setXfermode(null);" and everything works as expected  :)